# Can a father dissown his oldest son and make his younger son the bachor?

Tags: halacha, bechor-firstborn

It is well known Esav sold his 'birthright' to Yaakov. Can a father decide arbitrarily which son he wants to favor as his bachor? If so -under what conditions?

Comment: Yosef and Reuvein

Comment: The chumash says explicitly that he cant make his beloved wife's son the bchor if he isnt

Comment: I'm just thinking about the grounds for a father with one wife simply wanting to ignore the older son.

Comment: Why should it make a difference how many wives he has got.

Comment: does your above citation cover the whole subject?

Comment: No I dont think so. I think there are ways he can do it. I havent the mishnayof of yesh nochlin to hand at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a father says "my bechor will not take double" or says "he will inherit like a regular son" it is invalid. It violates the commandment of not diverting inheritance Devarim 21:16

If the son agrees to give up his portion some permit it. Nesivos 281:6

See pischei choshen hilchos yerushah 4:6-8 for a complete discussion .

A firstborn's portion is unchangeable. A non firstborn may be increased since he is receiving an inheritance. A non inheriting relative (daughter among sons) cannot be set to receive an inheritance

The details for actually setting this up and possible workarounds such as writing a halachik will are complex and will often not be done properly without the assistance of professional halachik advisers (Business Halacha Institute and dinonline.org among others.)

Comment: SO a man cannot completely diss-inherit his son -halachikly anyway.

Comment: @seekinclarity only bechor. Regular son can be chsnged